# Expected data not getting fetched with nested Google DataStore queries written in Express/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to implement nested `datastore` queries in `Node/express`. Parent query is a simple `get` request on a `kind` and the child query will aggregate a particular column of other `kind` based on a specific column value of parent `kind` results fetched above. 
Please check the code below for better insight.

```
app.get("/api/venues/", (req, res, next) => {
  const query = datastore
  .createQuery('venue');

  // parent query run here
  query.run().then(([venuesList]) => {
  venuesList.forEach(
    venue => {
      startDate = moment(new Date()).format('L');
      endDate = moment(new Date()).startOf('week').format('L');
      const queryVenueInvoice = datastore
      .createQuery('invoices')
      .filter('targetacntkey', '=', venue.userid);

      // child query run here
      queryVenueInvoice.run().then(([invoicesList]) => {
        const filteredInvoiceList = invoicesList.filter( invoice =>
          (new Date(invoice.timestamp).toISOString().split('T')[0])
          <= startDate && (new Date(i.timestamp).toISOString().split('T')[0]) >= (endDate));

          venue['weeklySummary'] = filteredInvoiceList.reduce((sum, invoice) => {
            return sum + invoice.totalamount; }, 0);
        })

      venue['venueKey'] = venue[datastore.KEY]
    }
    );
  // venuesList.forEach(venue => console.log(venue));
  res.status(200).json(
    {
      message: "Request was processed successfully!",
      venues: venuesList
    }
  );
})
})
```

I am able to get back the response as `venuesList` array populated with `venueKey`. However i am not able to see the aggregated property `weeklySummary` within the response. What am i missing here? Any someone guide me so see the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to do async operations in your venuesList.forEach()

So the response is being sent before those complete.  You will need to use something like

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}

app.get("/api/venues/", (req, res, next) => {
  const query = datastore
  .createQuery('venue');

    query.run().then(async ([venuesList]) => {
      await asyncForEach(venuesList, async(venue) => {
        startDate = moment(new Date()).format('L');
        endDate = moment(new Date()).startOf('week').format('L');
        const queryVenueInvoice = datastore
          .createQuery('invoices')
          .filter('targetacntkey', '=', venue.userid);

        // child query run here
        await queryVenueInvoice.run().then(([invoicesList]) => {...
```

Also I would place the res.status(200)... inside of the query.run().then(... and outside of the asyncForEach(...
I hope this helps